# How to count email addresses grouped by domain?

Tags: mysql

Given email addresss data like this, I need to display the number of users in each domain.:

```
+----------------------+
| email                |
+----------------------+
| richardg07@gmail.com |
| anolimous@yahoo.com  |
| binnerts@yahoo.com   |
| retsel@yahoo.com     |
| Val@gmail.com        |
| mayaman@yahoo.com    |
| marylaine@yahoo.com  |
| richardg07@gmail.com |
| shaider07@lycos.com  |
| yayabelles@yahoo.com |
+----------------------+
```

I want output like this:

```
+----------------------+-------------+
| Email Acount         | Total Users |
+----------------------+-------------+
| gmail.com            | 3           |
| lycos.com            | 1           |
| yahoo.com            | 6           |
+----------------------+-------------+
```

How should I do that in MySQL?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to describe the question at all. What does this have to do with using MySQL on the command line?

Comment: yes mysql command line. and using xampp control panel.

Comment: A cleaner step for this would be to store local part and domain name in separate fields. Only then MySQL can unfold its full strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1) AS `Email Acount`, COUNT(*) AS `Total Users`
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY `Email Acount`
```

MySQL `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37264/1)

Comment: you got it first. same as sadikhasan , sorry ididnt notice , my first time. anyway your answer is correct however the output is not right , ill check it tomorrow in my lab subject. thanks

Comment: It works correctly when I try it. See my sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: finally it is order by 'Email Account'

Comment: So add an `ORDER BY` clause, WTP? That's a totally trivial addition and has no effect on the overall logic.